# How to create a formula to output a number for a picklist value, and reject an N/A value?

Tags: formula, number, null

In creating a formula to stamp the numerical value of a picklist, I am having difficulty with an "N/A" value. Right now, the picklist has 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,N/A as options to choose from. I am using the VALUE(TEXT(PICKLIST__c)) formula to get the numerical value in a number field. However, I am receiving an #Error! whenever the "N/A" value is chosen, as it is not a number.

Due to the fact that I need to rollup this numerical formula field, I need a way to treat the N/A as a null value. Can you assist? Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind, I believe I've solved my own issue with the formula: IF(CONTAINS(TEXT(PICKLIST__c), "N/A"), NULL, VALUE(TEXT(PICKLIST__c)))

Comment: You should probably either post that as the answer or delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I believe I've solved my own issue with the formula: IF(CONTAINS(TEXT(PICKLIST__c), "N/A"), NULL, VALUE(TEXT(PICKLIST__c)))